# Barplot of total vs part with percents (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I've been trying for some time to achieve the following graph:

Based on similar such as this:

```
Age  Total  Infected  Percent
[0,10]  619 17  2.75    
(10,20] 711 24  3.38    
(20,30] 318 25  7.86    
(30,40] 307 23  7.49    
(40,50] 421 37  8.79    
(50,60] 299 29  9.70    
(60,70] 172 21  12.21   
(70,80] 93  22  23.66   
(80,90] 53  6   11.32   
(90,100] 5  0   0.00
```

I need to plot a barplot of two variables (one being the number of evaluated patients and the other being the number of evaluated patients that is infected), by ranges of age; and plot on top of each group the percentage of infected patients.

It should look like the following image:

[image]

With this code I plot the barplot of the two variables, but then I don't know how to place the percents..

```
longPlotData <- plotData %>%
    pivot_longer(!Age, names_to = "Status", values_to = "Num")

ggplot(longPlotData, aes(fill=Status, y=Num, x=Age)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width=0.3)
```

Any advise?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can reshape to long and then keep the `Percent` variable together with `Age`. After that you can adjust the label and use `geom_text()` to add the values on top of bars. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
longPlotData <- plotData %>%
  mutate(Age=factor(Age,levels = unique(Age),ordered = T)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Age,Percent), names_to = "Status", values_to = "Num")
#Plot
longPlotData %>%
  mutate(Percent=ifelse(Status=='Infected',NA,Percent))%>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=Status, y=Num, x=Age)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width=0.3)+
  geom_text(aes(label=Percent),vjust=-0.5,fontface='bold')+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, this definitly did the job.